# Troubles uninstalling oh-my-zsh?

Tags: config, uninstallation, zsh

I'm on OSX and want to switch back to my original zsh config from [oh-my-zsh](http://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), however when I run the `uninstall` script it gives me an error:

```
$ sudo uninstall oh-my-zsh

>> Preparing Uninstall...
   Uninstall Began...
   Uninstall Failed...
   Reason: ErrorMissingBundle
```

Can anyone please tell me what this means? Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Have you tried just running the commands from uninstall script by hand? It's really straight forward: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/tools/uninstall.sh. For the most part it just removes OMZ and attempts to restore a back up file:

```
rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh
rm ~/.zshrc
cp ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've already figured out how to do it by hand after a short while of figuring it out about a couple weeks or so ago. I never did it exactly in the given process, however my original zsh config works fine.

Comment: This works for me, but, if you want to reinstall zsh, you must copy manually the .zshrc file again

Comment: Be really careful with this! If you've modified your `.zshrc` a lot in the meantime since you installed ohmyzsh, simplying removing `~/.zshrc` without backing it up first will cause you to lose all of your config.

Comment: This code messed up my terminal for some reason and it did not work but "sh ~/.oh-my-zsh/tools/uninstall.sh" works fine

Answer (score 21):

In new version, just run `uninstall_oh_my_zsh` from the command-line.

See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#uninstalling-oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
/usr/bin/chsh -s /bin/bash
rm ~/.zshrc
brew uninstall zsh --force
```

Answer (score 4):

just run `uninstall_oh_my_zsh`
from here
https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#uninstalling-oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 1):

Updating this for wsl2 as per today state, instead of `~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh` it should be `~/.shell.pre-oh-my-zsh`, complete list of commands that worked for me is:

```
rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh
rm ~/.zshrc
cp ~/.shell.pre-oh-my-zsh ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Running `uninstall_oh_my_zsh` or manually `sh ~/.oh-my-zsh/tools/uninstall.sh` worked fine on mine.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to uninstall directly since I was getting zsh:command rm not found

so I did the following:

```
/usr/bin/chsh -s /bin/bash
```

on terminal preference, I switched back to the default Login shell
and ran the below command

```
rm ~/.zshrc

brew uninstall zsh --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Jest use this commands

1st **pkg uninstall termux-ohmyzsh**
2nd **rm-rf termux-ohmyzsh**

2nd is remove file from your storage and 1st is remove package from your storage.
Then check your file type **ls** its remove.

Answer (score -1):

simply use the following command:

```
/usr/bin/chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: This just changes your default shell to be bash, 1) not uninstall OMZ, 2) doesn't restore Zsh, 3) makes it not even use Zsh anymore