# Fixing colour unmatch in ls and recommendation with omz

Tags: macos, terminal

After installing the latest update, the recommendation colour changed to purple, which is challenging to see. Is there any way to change it to another colour, like red? I tried to change the font colour or ANSI colour, but it does not work.

[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65339599/11286032) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug during the Update since the recommendation colour should be the same as the one that comes with ls. There are two ways to solve it.

**Solution 1: Uninstalling Oh my Zsh completely and reinstall again (if uninstall_oh_my_zsh doesn't solve the problem)**

```
rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh
rm ~/.zshrc
cp ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Thanks to @Steve McKinney
*Source*: {[Troubles uninstalling oh-my-zsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813983/troubles-uninstalling-oh-my-zsh)}

**Solution 2: Add a row in the zshrc file**

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```

and use https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/ to pick the colours you want

Thanks to Marc Cornellà  {*Source*: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/discussions/11559}

Hopes this help anyone with the same issue.